# Create a design pattern for objects in two categories, both covering all objects

Tags: class, design-patterns, class-diagram

I would like to design a class diagram for the following problem:

From one perspective in my domain, my elements ("ELEMENTs") are either **input** elements or **output** elements, but not both.

From another perspective, they are either **nodes** or **arrows** (but not both).

For example, the element **e1** can have only one of the following situations:

1) be an input node

2) be an output node

3) be an input arrow

4) be an output arrow.

I would like to encode this without using constraint (like OCL)

So far, I've come up with the following design diagram (grey classes are abstract):
[image]

**My Question:**
Is there a more efficient pattern that would fit this problem more accurately, without multi-inheritance?

Comment: As far my understanding goes, your design is close with CQRS. In CQRS, it use strategy pattern and interface, not multiple inheritance for handler. However I'm not a big fan of CQRS so I can't say much.

Answer (score 2):

With your requirements and as per my understanding, I'd rather use `Strategy` pattern instead of inheritance. So it would be two different behaviors

1. Input/Output
2. Node/Arrow (Could all it Shape)

And Element would contain all the functions related to those two behaviors (as it has both of these). So the diagram would be like this (The Element is only referring to IShapeBehavior and IInputOutputBehavior)

[image]

Comment: What is your intended type of relationship between InputBehaviour and IInputOutputBehaviour by drawing a straight line between them? (similarly between OutputBehaviour and IInputOutputBehaviour)

Comment: IInputOutputBehavior has the operations related to both input and output behaviours, and InputBehavior and OutputBehavior implement it.

Comment: If InputBehaviour implements IInputOutputBehaviour interface, the line between InputBehaviour and IInputOutputBehaviour should be a dashed line with a hollow end at IInputOutputBehaviour side; similarly for the other lines. see [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC267834.png)